# How to configure Syntastic to process mixed Jinja/Html files correctly?

Tags: plugin-syntastic

I've searched around for how to configure vim/syntastic to process mixed Jinja/Html files but haven't found the configuration steps with the right linter for Jinja/Html files. Does anyone know if there is a way to configure Syntastic to handle filetype jinja.html?

The issue that caused me to consider this issue is a Jinja/Html template file with this line

```
<li><a href="{{ url_for('about') }}">About</a></li>
```

Vim and Syntastic both report the filetype as jinja.html so they are aware of the mixed file.

The html/tidy checker report these error:

```
layout.html|23 col 11 warning| <a> escaping malformed URI reference
layout.html|23 col 11 warning| <a> illegal characters found in URI
```

After checking I think this is correct Jinja/Html syntax. If so, then tidy is probaby not the right checker. Is there a checker or checker configuration that checks the syntax of mixed Jinja/Html files?

Comment: Syntastic doesn't care about the contents of your files, it just runs third-party linters against them and show you the results. Then `filetype=jinja.html` just means syntastic will (try to) run linters for both `jinja` and `html`. Since there is no syntastic linter for `jinja`, you only get your file checked as `html`. Whether the results are useful or not is up to you, syntastic doesn't magically invent linters for random formats. For better results you'd need a linter specifically for Jinja, and a syntastic checker for it. Neither seem to exist at this time though.

Comment: Thank you, I'll update the question to include asking about a jinja or jinja/html linter.  I haven't found one but maybe someone will point one out or one will come available.